# How do I bind a :src for an image in the child component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am attempting to render a list of components. All the data properties are displaying correctly except the img src url.

the files/folders are :

CryptContent.vue  - contains the v-for

- the component to render
  assets/ - contains the images

The CryptContent.vue contain:

```
<template>
<OwnedCardContent
            v-for="card in allCards"
            :id="card.id"
            :name="card.name"
            :cost="card.cost"
            :cset="card.cset"
            :edition_total="card.edition_total"
            :level="card.card_level"
            :unlock_czxp="card.unlock_czxp"
            :buy_czxp="card.buy_czxp"
            :transfer_czxp="card.transfer_czxp"
            :sacrifice_czxp="card.sacrifice_czxp"
            :url="card.graphic"
            :card_class="card.bg"
></OwnedCardContent>
</template>

<script>
allcards : [
      {id:0, name: 'Jim Zombie',graphic: './assets/jim.svg', cost: 300, cset: 'We like to party set', edition_total: ' of 100',unlock_czxp : '1,300,300',card_level: 80, buy_czxp: '1,800',transfer_czxp: '100', sacrifice_czxp: '2,300',bg: 'card-bg card-bg-6'},
]
 </script>`
```

OwnedCardContent.vue contains:

```
<template>
<div id="1" :class="card_class">
            <img class="card-img" :src="url" />
            <span class="card-edition">#1{{edition_total}}</span>
            <div class="card-item-name text-center">{{name}}<br>{{cset}}</div>
            <div class="card-czxp text-left">{{unlock_czxp}}</div>
            <div class="card-level">{{level}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'OwnedCardContent',
props: ['id','name','url','edition_total','cset','unlock_czxp','level','cost','buy_czxp','transfer_czxp','sacrifice_czxp','card_class'],
data () {
return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The image won't render. When I inspect the code, the correct value from allCards graphic gets injected into the page..

when I remove :src and put just src="./assets/jim.svg" it works.

so I assume it's how webpack prepares it maybe ? I dont know enough about it :(

any help would be super helpful, thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With webpack images are considered as modules so you should import or require them like :

```
 allcards : [ {id:0, name: 'Jim Zombie',graphic: require('./assets/jim.svg'), ....]
```

or

```
  import img from './assets/jim.svg';
  export default{
       ...
         data(){
             return {
               allcards : [ {id:0, name: 'Jim Zombie',graphic: img, ....],
                 ...
                }
             }
         ...

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you try use method for src

```
getImgUrl(path) {
    var images = require.context('../assets/', false, /\.png$/)
    return images('./' + path + ".png")
  }

<div class="col-lg-2" v-for="pic in pics">
   <img :src="getImgUrl(pic)" v-bind:alt="pic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
<img v-attr="src:imgUrl">
```