# NuxtServerError: Cannot find module 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm trying to dynamically upload images into a vuetify carousel component from a folder I've added to the project path called 'Main'.

[image]

My component looks like:

```
<template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>


<script>
function getImagePaths() {
  // var images = require.context('../../main/img/', false, /\.png$/)
  var images = require.context("../../main/", false, /\.png$/);
  // var images = require.context('/main/', false, /\.png$/)
  console.log("images", images);
  return images;
}

export default {
  methods: {
    imgUrl: getImagePaths()
  }
};
```

I'm getting the:

```
NuxtServerError: Cannot find module 'undefined'
```

(screenshot above) How can I fix this?

EDIT: if I change the Script tag to:

```
  <script>
// function getImagePaths() {
//   // Load locally as a function.
//   const fs = require("fs-extra");

//   var requireContext = require("require-context");
//   // var images = require.context('../../main/img/', false, /\.png$/)
//   var images = require.context("../../main/", false, /\.png$/);
//   // var images = require.context('/main/', false, /\.png$/)
//   console.log("images", images);
//   return images;
// }

// export default {
//   methods: {
//     imgUrl: getImagePaths()
//   }
// };
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/squirrel.jpg'
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg'
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg'
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It works as expected.

Comment: what do you get if try a source like `https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim , please see edit.

Comment: please look at this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950105/how-do-i-bind-a-src-for-an-image-in-the-child-component/53952017#53952017)

Comment: Thank you I was not aware that images had to be imported as modules. Regarding your answer you have the following line: '  import img from './assets/jim.svg'; I'm trying to first get a list of paths to all the .png files. I don't want to hardcode in the src paths. 
'

Comment: please edit your question by adding what your use case and what wen wrong if you adopt my answer?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim before I do that -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015346/nuxt-could-not-compile-template