# NUXT: Could not compile template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm getting started with nuxt. My project structure in the screenshot, I've got a vuetify carousel component that was working fine with urls as the src. Now I want to try to serve local static files. I tried:

```
    <template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>


    <script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: '/static/52lv.PNG'
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg'
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg'
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

but now when I run the dev server I get:

```
$ npm run dev

> nuxt4@1.0.0 dev ....\js\nuxt4
> nuxt

i Preparing project for development                                                                                                                   20:23:25
i Initial build may take a while                                                                                                                      20:23:25
√ Builder initialized                                                                                                                                 20:23:25

ERROR  Could not compile template ....nuxt4\\node_modules\\@nuxt\\vue-app\\template\\App.js: Cannot resolve "~/assets/style/app.styl" from "E:\ENVS\js\nuxt4\assets\style\app.styl"

at Promise.all.templatesFiles.map (node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:6009:17)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `app.styl` file appears to have been moved from `assets/style` to `static/style`. Was this intentional?

Comment: yes -  I'm trying to figure out how to serve local files, I was following https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/ . I couldn't figure out the path from the  assets folder so i renamed the folder as static to try from there. That's when the error happened.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact issue, it turned out to be a path issue in my nuxt.config.js file under css and scripts sections. I added a assets folder with sub folders and files within them such as static > assets > etc but in my config file it was ~/assets.

I changed it to ~/static/assets/ and now it compiles correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting out with Nuxt.js too! So far, at least for my navbar where I have the static pages linked to, I have my static files routed in the `nuxt.config.js` file under `generate : { routes: ["file/", "file2/"] }`. Each those files are .vue files under my `pages` directory. Now, when I run `npm run dev`, I can click into each of those files on my navbar and they come up perfectly. Hope this helps! Comment below if I'm unclear.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake. Accidentally said components instead of pages. Corrected.