# Render local image in Vue component where image location is stored in data attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to render an image from my assets folder in a Vue project. The image displays when I hardcode it in using any of the following methods:

```
<img src="../assets/my_image.jpg"></img>
<img :src="require('../assets/my_image.jpg')"></img>
<img src="@/assets/my_image.jpg"></img>
<img :src="require('@/assets/my_image.jpg')"></img>
```

However I can't get the image to render I store that location in a data attribute called `imgLocation`, where `imgLocation='../assets/my_image.jpg'` or `imgLocation='@/assets/my_image.jpg'`:

```
<img :src="imgLocation"></img>
<img :src="require(imgLocation)"></img>
```

The first element shows no image and logs nothing to the console. The second element shows the following errors in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/my_image.jpg'"
>
> Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/my_image.jpg'
>       at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./src/components sync recursive (app.js:6618), :2:10)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950105/how-do-i-bind-a-src-for-an-image-in-the-child-component/53952017#53952017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case the bindings are evaluated at run-time. You want the path to be resolved at build-time. So you should probably do `imgLocation: require('../assets/my_image.jpg')` or `imgLocation: require('@/assets/my_image.jpg')` in the `data` section of your component.

Comment: @Boussadjra Thanks!