# v-bind image src with a computed property in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a JSON file with some objects, which are getting rendered out using a computed property

JSON:

```
{
     "id": 6,
     "formula": "2+2",
     "description": "Just a description.",
     "image": "../assets/img/id6.png",
     "answers": [
        { "answerId": 0, "answerInput": "Funktion", "correct": false},
        { "answerId": 1, "answerInput": "Relation", "correct": true}
     ]
}
```

All data is getting rendered out with no errors.

script tag:

```
computed:{
  filterById(){
      return this.exercises.find(exercises => exercises.id === this.exId)
    }
  }
```

template tag:

```
<div class="task-description">
  <h2>{{ filterById.description }}</h2>
  <img :src="`${filterById.image}`" alt="">
</div>
```

but for some reason I can not render the image, I am sure the path to the image is correct.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of the issue?

Comment: Excuse me, I am new to this. What is a fiddle?

Comment: No problem, if you could reproduce your issue in a fiddle like this one: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue then it would make it easier for us to debug and help you out. :)

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952017/8172857

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link. The only difference is that in my project I have my data with the exercises in an external JSON file and not in the script tag itself. https://jsfiddle.net/zu548Lky/

Comment: I tried using the solution with using the method, that @Boussadjra Brahim mentioned and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end I used the following method:

```
getImgUrl(path) {
    var images = require.context('../assets/img/')
    return images('./' + path + ".png")
}
```

and outputed the image like this

```
<img v-if="filterById.id == 7 || filterById.id == 6" :src="getImgUrl(filterById.image)">
```