# Why does javascript expression in Vue binding <g-image> does not work?

Tags: vue.js, gridsome

I have a use case where I have to bind the `src` attribute of the `<g-image>` tags dynamically. I have learned that I can use [javascrpt expressions in `v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions), so I proceeded on. But here's the paradox:

```js
<g-image :src="'~/images/blocks.png'" width="500"/> // does not work
<g-image src="~/images/blocks.png" width="500"/> //works!
```

Why does one work and the other does not, even though, they shoud evaluate to the same values?
I am planning to then use it as `<g-image :src="'~/images/'+imageName+'.png'" width="500"/>`

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950105/how-do-i-bind-a-src-for-an-image-in-the-child-component/53952017#53952017

Comment: Have you tried to use v-bind:src instead of :src the shorthand syntax (:src) may not work if you are working directly inside html (iirc)

Answer (score 0):

[Gridsome documentation](https://gridsome.org/docs/images/#usage-in-vue-templates)

> The `src` attribute and options like `width`, `height` and `quality` must be static values because they are compiled into an object which contains URLs and other information that will be rendered into an `img` tag

I admit Im not a regular Gridsome user and everything which follows comes from my understanding of Vue/Webpack, Gridsome docs and [this issue](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/292)

`g-image` is component provided by Gridsome intended to make use of responsive images easier. Most of the job is done during **build time** - they use some Webpack magic to process Vue templates. If `g-image` is found, it's `src` attribute is read and if it contains path to existing local image, they take the image, generate multiple copies of it with different sizes and add [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) attribute which allows the browser to decide which image to download depending on screen size...

Important thing is this is all happening at build time. It means your app *is not running* which means it is not possible to evaluate any JS dynamic expression used for `src` (probably based on app state)!

It may seem as using `require()` (which is Webpack construct which [allows some dynamic content](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)) makes it work but you will loose main `g-image` feature which is automatic generation of responsive image...

This is not an issue easy to solve on Gridsome side (look how old the issue is and how much attention from maintainers it gets). If you really want dynamic responsive images, you will need to use simple `img` and generate image variants (and `srcset`) some other way. Or you can use Cloudinary to generate those images on the fly....